# Approximations to define de Itô Integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am using Oksendal's book of Stochastic Differential Equations. We define the space $\mathcal{V}(S,T)$ as the set of fuctions, $f$, that verify

1. $f(t,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{B} \times\mathcal{F}$ mesurable.
2. $\mathbb{E}[\int_S^T|f(t,\omega)|^2 dt] < \infty$.

3. $ f$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted.

To define the Itô Integral he approximates $f$ by simple functions. In an intermediate step, he wants to approximate $h$ a bounded function in $\mathcal{V}$ by a sequence of bounded and continous functions $g_n$, defined as:

\begin{equation}
g_n(t,\omega) = \int_0^t \phi_n(t-s) h(s, \omega) ds,
\end{equation}
where $\phi_n$ is a non-negative function which takes non-zero values in [$\frac{-1}{n},0]$ and also $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi_n = 1.$

How can I prove that each $g_n(t, \omega)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted?

Comment: I don't have a proper answer now, but notice that the mollifier $\phi_n$ doesn't "look into the future", so it makes sense to think that the result is indeed adapted

Comment: by the way shouldn't $h$ be evaluated at time $s$ inside the integral?

Comment: Yes, corrected. Thank you very much